# Check whether a relationship exist in neo4j database is not working

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

When i created two node and their relation using transaction as shown below, i am able to use graph.match() to check if relation exist.

```
from py2neo import Graph, Node, Relationship, NodeSelector
g = Graph('http://localhost:7474/db/data', user='uname', password='pass')

tx = g.begin()

a = Node("Person", name="Alice")
tx.create(a)

b = Node("Person", name="Bob")
tx.create(b)

ab = Relationship(a, "KNOWS", b)
tx.create(ab)

tx.commit()

relations = g.match(start_node=a, rel_type="KNOWS", end_node=b)
list(relations) // this returns [(alice)-[:KNOWS]->(bob)]
```

Later i tried to pass *start_node* and *end_node* to graph.match() function as shown below, but it didn't work instead returned **ERROR : Nodes for relationship match end points must be bound**

```
d = Node("Person", name="Alice")
e = Node("Person", name="Bob")
relations = g.match(start_node=d, rel_type="KNOWS", end_node=e)
list(relations) // this returns error " Nodes for relationship match end points must be bound "
```

What is wrong with the above code to fetch an exixting relationship between Alice and Bob

Comment: Isn't `Node()` used for creating nodes? I'm not sure your code is matching to existing nodes in the graph.

Comment: after your question, it made me think and i tried something and that worked. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in following code

```
d = Node("Person", name="Alice")
e = Node("Person", name="Bob")
relations = g.match(start_node=d, rel_type="KNOWS", end_node=e)
list(relations) // this returns error " Nodes for relationship match end points must be bound "
```

is that **Node** is used to create new node as @InverseFalcon mentioned in the comment. it did not points to actual node in server. it worked to check relation at the time of creation ( First set of code in my question ) of nodes is because after creating the nodes the **Node** class return node object.

Following code worked for my project

```
d = g.run("MATCH (a:Person) WHERE a.name={b} RETURN a", b="Alice")
list_d = list(d)
start_node = list_d[0]['a']
e = g.run("MATCH (a:Person) WHERE a.name={b} RETURN a", b="Bob")
list_e = list(e)
end_node = list_e[0]['a']
relations = g.match(start_node=start_node, rel_type="KNOWS", end_node=end_node)
```